# I want to create party planner website. I am not able to get the output. When I am clicking on submit button it just getting clear

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create party planner website but I am not able to get the output. When I am clicking on submit button it just getting clear.

I am neither getting the window alert messages nor the exact output.
The output should be:-

1. Check the valid event date 1 if its ok move to point 2 else display windows alert message.
2. now check the valid event date 2 again if its ok move to point 3 else display the message.
3. Check the valid count of guest if its >50 then move to point 4 else display alert message.
4. After completing all the steps just calculate the billAmt and display it.

```js
function validateEventDate1(eventDate) {
  eventDate = document.getElementById("eventDate").value;
  var currentDate = new Date();
  if (eventDate < currentDate.getDate()) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  if (false) {
    window.alert("Event Date can't be today or before!!");
  }
}

function validateEventDate2(eventDate) {
  eventDate = document.getElementById("eventDate").value;
  var currentDate = new Date();
  if (currentDate.getDate() < eventDate) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  if (false) {
    window.alert("Event Date cannot be just 1 or 2 days after current date!!");
  }
}

function validateGuestCount(gcount) {
  gcount = document.getElementById("gcount").value;
  if (gcount < 50) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  if (false) {
    window.alert("Guest count must be minimum 50!!");
  }
}
var billAmt;

function calculateBillAmount(gcount, cname, email) {
  gcount = document.getElementById("gcount").value;
  cname = document.getElementById("myName").value;
  email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  if (document.getElementById("wedding").checked === true && document.getElementById("veg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 400;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("wedding").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 500;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("wedding").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === true && document.getElementById("veg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 650;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("wedding").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === false && document.getElementById("veg").checked === false) {
    billAmt += 10000;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("naming").checked === true && document.getElementById("veg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 350;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("naming").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 400;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("naming").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === true && document.getElementById("veg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 500;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("naming").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === false && document.getElementById("veg").checked === false) {
    billAmt += 10000;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("birthday").checked === true && document.getElementById("veg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 250;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("birthday").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 300;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("birthday").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === true && document.getElementById("veg").checked === true) {
    billAmt = gcount * 400;
    return billAmt;
  } else if (document.getElementById("birthday").checked === true && document.getElementById("nonveg").checked === false && document.getElementById("veg").checked === false) {
    billAmt += 10000;
    return billAmt;
  }
  billAmt = billAmt + (billAmt * 0.18);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Dear" + cname + ",</br>" + "We confirm your Order.The amount is Rs : " + billAmt + ",</br>" + "Further details will be mailed on " + "</br>" + "email.";
}

function estimateAmount() {
  validateEventDate1(eventDate);
  validateEventDate2(eventDate);
  validateGuestCount;
  calculateBillAmount(gcount, cname, email);

}
```

```css
#partyPlanner {
  font-family: Arial;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #5f9ea0;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#partyPlanner td,
#partyPlanner th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFCC99;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff6347;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
}

.checkboxes label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.checkboxes input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkboxes label span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#result {
  color: #770080;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading1">Zee Party Planner</h1>
<form onsubmit="return estimateAmount()">
  <table id="partyPlanner">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="menu">
          <h3 id="heading2">Fill out this Form</h3>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="basicinfo" colspan="2">Basic Info </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter your Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z ]*"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" required="required">Male <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" required="required">Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mobile Number</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mobileNumber" id="mobileNumber" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile No" pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required="required"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email ID</td>
      <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email id" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="partyinfo" colspan="2">Party Info</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Event Date</td>
      <td><input type="date" name="eventDate" id="eventDate" placeholder="Enter Event Date" required="required"></td>
      <tr>
        <td>Event Type</td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <select id="event" name="event">
            <option id="birthday" value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
            <option id="wedding" value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
            <option id="naming" value="Naming Ceremony">Naming Ceremony</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Event Location</td>
        <td><textarea id="address" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Your Address" required="required"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Expected Guest Count</td>
        <td> <input type="number" id="gcount" name="gcount" placeholder="Enter Guest Count" required="required"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Food Type</td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div class="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="food" id="veg" value="veg" /> <span>Veg</span><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="food" id="nonveg" value="nonveg" /> <span>Non-Veg </span><br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>How did you reach out to us</td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="radio" name="referral" id="Friends" value="Friends">&nbsp;Friends<br>
          <input type="radio" name="referral" id="Family" value="Family">&nbsp;Family<br>
          <input type="radio" name="referral" id="ad" value="Advertisement">&nbsp;Advertisement<br>
          <input type="radio" name="referral" id="nPaper" value="New Paper">&nbsp;News paper<br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="reset" value="Clear" id="reset">
        </td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div id="result"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you doing anything to prevent the form from reloading the page? Submitting a form passes it to the page specified in the `action` attribute, and without an action attribute it's passed back to the page it's on.

Comment: @j08691 sorry i m not getting this as I am newbie in this. Can u help me?

Comment: How are you binding the submit to the javascript? I don't see any way the submit button will fire a javascript function.

Comment: @SeanLawton `<form onsubmit="return estimateAmount()">`

Comment: @SeanLawton when I am clicking on Submit it should display the output as onsubmit form is used in HTML by calling the <form onsubmit="return estimateAmount()">

Comment: You never prevent the form from being submitted the normal way.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so I tested out your website, and it looks to be that the phone number thing is asking for a very specific format, which can create problems. I tried `123-456-7890`, and `(123) 456-7890`, then `1234567890`, and every time it said 'Please match the requested format.' Check to see if you are asking for a specific format, and delete that code, because that seems to be the only thing causing a problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).